# Cucumber Event Handling in Gradle Project

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cucumber

I would like to add an event handler to my Gradle project. I work with cucumber and selenium and I need the event handling to get the text from the steps. For example:

`Given I am on Login Page`

I need the string "I am on Login Page" to perform further actions. I have read that you can access the step text with the Event Handler via the event, for example like this

`event.getTestStep();`

Here's what I tried:

```
package hit.listeners;

import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventHandler;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventPublisher;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestStepStarted;

public class Listener implements EventListener {


  private final EventHandler<TestStepStarted> runStartedHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() {
    @Override
    public void receive(TestStepStarted event) {
      System.out.println("Current TestStep:" +event.getTestStep(););

    }
  };

  @Override
  public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, runStartedHandler);
  }


}
```

When I run the test now, the Event Listener does not seem to react because there is no console output. Any ideas what I should do to make the event listener respond?

Tried to register the Listener at build.gradle under the cucumber tasks:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, test
    doLast {
        new File("report/cucumber.log").delete()
        new File("report/cucumber.json").delete()
        new File("report/cucumber-usage.json").delete()

        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            args = [
                '--strict', 
                '--plugin', 'hit.listeners.Listener',
                '--plugin', 'pretty',
                '--plugin', 'html:report',
                '--plugin', 'pretty:report/cucumber.log',
                '--plugin', 'json:report/cucumber.json', 
                '--plugin', 'usage:report/cucumber-usage.json',
                '--glue', 'hit.steps', 
                '--glue', 'hit.hooks', 
                '--tags', "${tags}", 
                "--${monochrome}", 
                'features',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the listener anywhere? It will not work only by defining it.

Comment: Hey, yes i have tried to register the listener in the build.gradle under the cucumber tasks, but i am not sure if this is right. I have inserted the section of build.gradle above.

Comment: So show how you did it.

Comment: Please have a look I put the snippet above.

Comment: Gradle by default doesn't include test output. Try using `./gradlew test --rerun-tasks --info`.